# How to propagate message to children on a Mithril Widget

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

I have a mithril `ListWidget` that displays a list of `Items`. The icon you see on the right allows to expand and collapse the details. It is a field "expanded" in each Item `vnode` state.

Now I want to collapse the rest of children when a children is expanded, so only one expanded children is displayed.

[image]

So `ListWidget` adds a function "`requestCChildrenCollapse`" to the attributes of each `Item` children. Now when you click on one children expand button, that function is called to collapse all children before expanding this one.

My problem is, I don't know how to access the `ListItems` `vnodes` from the `List` context. `vnode.children` is empty. `vnode.instance.children` do contain the children, but in the docs say this is a private member and must not be used. Besides they are "fullpage" chidren.

So what's the best practice to accomplish this?

ListWidget

```
ListWidget = () => {
     view: (vnode) => m(".fullpage", 
        [
            m("div.flexrow", [
                m(
                     "ul.listitems",
                     Object.keys(ListItem.get()).map(id => m(ListItem, {
                        id,
                        collapseChildrenRequest: () => {
                            for (const child of vnode.children) console.log(child);
                        }
                    }
                 )
            ])
        ]
     )
};
```

Children onclick:

```
onclick: () => {
vnodeView.attrs.collapseChildrenRequest();
vnodeView.state.isExpanded = !vnodeView.state.isExpanded;
},
```

Comment: Have you checked into oninit() lifecycle function for each of the DOM element? You can capture the Vnode generated at that time. You can capture the generated Vnode or you can further add them to event listners, add keys or id attributes.  May not be clean but you could even capture the Vnodes into your own array.

Comment: Playing with these things now that I better understand how mithril works. Thanks !